# Zend Framework ErrorController not working on live site?

Tags: zend-framework, error-handling, controller

My site is set up pretty much as per the Zend Quickstart guide. The default ErrorController works locally using MAMP. But now I've deployed it to my live site I get a blank page and a "500 Internal Server Error" according to FireBug when I go to an action that doesnt exist.

On my local server I get a 404 and a nicely formatted error page.

Any ideas anyone? I dont really know where to begin looking.

I'm confused :/

Thanks.

Comment: what does apache's error_log say? With mamp, this should be located under /Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_error_log

Comment: The MAMP log shows no error, as it shouldnt if PHP handles it. On my live server I get

PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 'Plugin by name 'Headtitle' was not found in the registry; used paths:\nZend_View_Helper_: 

and so on...

Oh.. I wonder if thats the problem. I noticed my local server doesnt kickup about the Headtitle helpe, but the live one does. And I dont have that set in the ErrorController. 

Hmm...

Answer (score 0):

Gentlemen, we have a winner!

So for some reason my live server gives me this error:

[Sun Oct 18 10:56:53 2009] [error] [client 118.209.152.109] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 'Plugin by name 'Headtitle' was not found in the registry; used paths:\nZend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/:/var/www/vhosts/lindengardens.com.au/httpdocs/application/views/helpers/' in /var/www/vhosts/lindengardens.com.au/httpdocs/library/Zend/Loader/PluginLoader.php:406\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/vhosts/lindengardens.com.au/httpdocs/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(1118): Zend_Loader_PluginLoader->load('Headtitle')\n#1 /var/www/vhosts/lindengardens.com.au/httpdocs/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(569): Zend_View_Abstract->_getPlugin('helper', 'headtitle')\n#2 /var/www/vhosts/lindengardens.com.au/httpdocs/library/Zend/View/Abstract.php(336): Zend_View_Abstract->getHelper('headtitle')\n#3 [internal function]: Zend_View_Abstract->__call('headtitle', Array)\n#4 /var/www/vhosts/lindengardens.com.au/httpdocs/application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml(32): Zend_View->headtitle()\n#5 /var/www/vhosts/lindengardens.com.au/httpdocs/library/Zend/View.php(108): incl in /var/www/vhosts/lindengardens.com.au/httpdocs/library/Zend/Loader/PluginLoader.php on line 406

I get the above error if I dont have something like

> $this->view->headTitle("Linden Gardens Rainforest Retreat B&B Mt Dandenong - Error Page");

set in the controller.

Just setting the headTitle fixed the problem - I wonder why that works fine on my local server :/

thanks.